# On a Windows 10 standard account can one disable application installation?

Tags: windows, windows-10, installation

On a machine I am trying to maintain, the user tends to want install any and all suspicious apps, "video codecs", etc. Can I prevent him/her from doing so?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way i can think of is using Group Policy.

**Computer Configurations > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Installer.**

Turn off the Windows Installer and users will no longer be able to install software or Suspicious apps.

Comment: I tried this. However the problem is it only stops installation of the seemingly few programs that use "Windows Installer". So most apps still install. Perhaps you can think of another way. One thing that occurs to me is preventing setting files with execute permission, but I have no idea if this is even possible.